# Начал писать игру(Кубик Рубика) на Ursina (Python) и столкнулся с ошибкой

Tags: python, разработка-игр, ursina

Начал писать игру(Кубик Рубика) на Ursina (Python), вот код:

```
from ursina import *
class Game(Ursina):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        window.fullscreen = True
        Entity(model='quad', scale=60, texture='white_cube', texture_scale=(60, 60), rotation_x=90, y=5, color=color.light_gray)
        Entity(model='sphere', scale=100, texture='textures/sky0', double_sided=True)
        Entity(model='models/xyz', texture='textures/xyz', scale=0.8)
        EditorCamera()
        camera.world_position = (0, 0, -15)
        self.load_game()
    def load_game(self):
        pass
    def input(self, key):
        super().input(key)
if __name__ == 'main':
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

А вот непонятная ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MAKSIM\PycharmProjects\rubicocubico\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    class Game(Ursina):
TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str
```

Comment: а откуда вы вообще этот код взяли?

Comment: с какой-то обучалки

Comment: у него работало всё

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой подход не сработает. Класс `Ursina` является `@singleton`.

Если ознакомиться с содержимым модуля - можно найти такое описание класса:

> The main class of Ursina. This class is a singleton, so you can only have one instance of it.

Советую ознакомиться с официальной документацией и минимальным примером:
https://www.ursinaengine.org/documentation.html
https://www.ursinaengine.org/introduction_tutorial.html

В ней вы сможете найти примеры работы с модулем. В отличие от "какой-то обучалки" - документация актуализируется. Возможно версия модуля в "обучалке" сильно отличается от актуальной.